# Angular 2 compiler-cli and less or sass

Tags: angular, angular-compiler-cli

I am using webpack with angular 2 and got sass working with it.  My next step is to get AOT working.  I am now stuck because ngc fails when it gets to my scss files as it can't find the imports.

The message is "Resource file not found..." and refers to an import statement.  It makes sense that the compiler might need the scss files process first but that would require the app to be built first and for it to successfully build the ngFactories need to be created.

Comment: Please embed the full error description (This doesn't have to include the stack trace) for context.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. The full error I'm receiving reads, "Error: Compilation failed. Resource file not found: /Users/dbudiac/Projects/editor/node_modules/bourbon/app/assets/stylesheets/bourbon". The path is valid, and `bourbon` is valid shorthand for `_bourbon.scss`.

Comment: Hi did you find out how to sort this issue, I'm facing the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Currently (2016/12/28), there is no way to handle it. Yes, that sucks.

The best way to do it is using node-sass to compile it before running ngc.

Here is the [example from angular-webpack2-starter](https://github.com/qdouble/angular-webpack2-starter#basic-scripts)

It seems like pretty inconvenience.

Here is the hope. [@ngtools/webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngtools/webpack)

With this, we can just use scss directly in component.

Comment: I guess you just saved me hours for further research

Comment: Is this still the case?